# Basic logging macro has mutex and scoped lock but lines are getting interlaced

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a really basic macro for logging. It is called by multiple threads.

I thought adding the mutex and scoped_lock would ensure the output does not get inter-mingled by the threads. However, the lines output in the Linux terminal are getting corrupted by the various threads.

What can I change to ensure the output shows a complete line without any corruption? Is there something simple I am missing?

```
#define LOG2(msg)                                                                          \
do                                                                                         \
{                                                                                          \
    static std::mutex mutex;                                                               \
    std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);                                              \
    {                                                                                      \
        std::cout << mynow() << " " << std::boolalpha << msg << std::endl;  \
    }                                                                                      \
} while (false)
```

Comment: There is no point in using such macros in modern C++. You can use functions and function templates instead. And in your case it is even wrong to use a macro. Had you written it as a non-templated function, then it would work as you expect it. If you need it templated, then you must move the mutex outside the function, since every specialization will have its own instance of the `static` variable otherwise.

Comment: Never create a macro for what can be done using a function. Especially with the [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) now available in C++20, there is no need to use macros for logging any more.

Comment: @heapunderrun unfortunately not everybody has luxury of using C++20 yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each call to your macro is declaring a different mutex object; that is why the synchronization isn’t working.  You need to instead declare a single mutex object that is used by all of the calls.

Simply declaring the mutex static isn’t enough because each macro invocation is in its own scope, so you end up with a separate static-variable for each invocation.

The easiest fix would be to convert your macro into a function; then it would behave the way you want.

Comment: If changing the macro into a function is not an option, the alternative is to move the mutex and logging into a singleton class which each macro invocation can then call into